# Why does Tensorflow cast int32/int32 to float64 and how to stop it?

Tags: tensorflow, implicit-conversion

I am dividing a tensor of type int32 by a tensor of type int32, and the result is float64. I can't find answers as to why this happens or if there are implicit rules behind how Tensorflow does this. I have not explicitly defined a dtype for any tensor, but I have checked all of them, and none of them have a 64bit type until after the division.

I've tried using different formulations of division such as tf.divide, all give the same result.

My code looks like:

```
a_cdf = a / tf.size(a)
```

with a being of type tf.int32.

What I want to get is the result as float32, so I can write my function without an explicit cast.

Comment: I'm trying to replicate your issue, but I get `TypeError: x and y must have the same dtype, got tf.float32 != tf.int32`. Can you post a self contained example which we can work on?

Comment: Are you using eager mode?

Comment: This is embarassing, both are type int32. I edited the question. I am not using eager mode, but I am using tf nightly 1.14, if that changes things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design. "True" division in TensorFlow (that is, real division) uses a [`_TRUEDIV_TABLE`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.14.0-rc0/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py#L932-L946) that specifies the casting rules for each type, and it currently reads:

```py
# Conversion table for __truediv__.  None entries mean no conversion required.
_TRUEDIV_TABLE = {
    dtypes.uint8: dtypes.float32,
    dtypes.int8: dtypes.float32,
    dtypes.uint16: dtypes.float32,
    dtypes.int16: dtypes.float32,
    dtypes.int32: dtypes.float64,
    dtypes.int64: dtypes.float64,
    dtypes.bfloat16: None,
    dtypes.float16: None,
    dtypes.float32: None,
    dtypes.float64: None,
    dtypes.complex64: None,
    dtypes.complex128: None,
}
```

Meaning that `int32` tensors will be converted to `float64`. If you want to obtain a `float32` as output, either use a smaller int type or cast your inputs to `float32`.

The rationale for this is another matter. If I had to guess, on the one hand I'd say if you are using 8 or 16 bit integers you are probably concerned about memory, so a smaller result type would make sense. But also, you could give the following argument:

```py
import numpy as np

# Compute smallest positive divisions with 16 and 32 bits
smallest_16bit_fraction = 1 / ((1 << 16) - 1)
smallest_32bit_fraction = 1 / (-(1 << 31))  # 31 bits because int32 is signed
# Compute one plus the smallest fractions with 32 and 64 bit floats
print(np.float32(1) + np.float32(smallest_16bit_fraction))
# 1.0000153
print(np.float64(1) + np.float64(smallest_16bit_fraction))
# 1.0000152590218967
print(np.float32(1) + np.float32(smallest_32bit_fraction))
# 1.0
print(np.float64(1) + np.float64(smallest_32bit_fraction))
# 0.9999999995343387
```

So you could think that, being a division of two integer values, you may want to mix the result with an integer, but as you can see for 32 bit integers, there will be cases where a 32 bit float will underflow.

But again, this is just guessing and more of a thought exercise than anything else.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response! This is probably another question entirely, but does casting results make TFs autodifferentiation any worse?

Comment: @Olfway Mmh, well I don't see why/how casting would affect autodifferentiation (other than precision), but differentiation is only defined for real values anyway. If you have integers in your computation, gradients won't propagate through them.

Comment: I did not know that! Does casting the integer before using it in calculations change that?

Comment: @Olfway It all depends on what gradients you want to compute. If you have a `tf.Variable` of integer type, you will simply not be able to update it with an optimizer, because no gradients can be computed for it. If you have a float variable `v` and an integer value `i` and you compute `v * tf.cast(i, tf.float32)`, then the gradients do backpropagate to `v` (the just do not backpropagate beyond `i`).

Comment: Got it thanks! Where does one find these kinds of information?

Comment: @Olfway Well, what kind of information exactly? I'm not sure there is any documentation explicitly saying that you cannot compute gradients for integers, I guess it's just implicitly assumed since the concept of gradients cannot really be applied to integers. You can dig into the gradient registry to see which ops have a gradient, but that doesn't tell the whole story since it depends on the dtype. So usually the easiest thing is to just do the operation and see if `tf.gradients` turns out `None`.